React-Spring not working on decreased height
I'm trying to animate the Box whenever the height changes. But it works only when the height of the Box is increased than the current but not when the height is decreased.
import { Box, Flex, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useSpring, animated } from '@react-spring/web';

const daysContent = [
  { day: 'Monday', info: 'Monday is 1st day.\n' },
  { day: 'Tuesday', info: 'Tuesday is 2nd day.\nTuesday is 2nd day.\n' },
  { day: 'Wednesday', info: 'Wednesday is 3rd day.\nWednesday is 3rd day.\nWednesday is 3rd day.\n' },
  { day: 'Thursday', info: 'Thursday is 4th day.\nThursday is 4th day.\nThursday is 4th day.\nThursday is 4th day.\n' },
  { day: 'Friday', info: 'Friday is 5th day.\nFriday is 5th day.\nFriday is 5th day.\nFriday is 5th day.\nFriday is 5th day.\n' },
  { day: 'Saturday', info: 'Saturday is 6th day.\nSaturday is 6th day.\nSaturday is 6th day.\nSaturday is 6th day.\nSaturday is 6th day.\nSaturday is 6th day.\n' },
  { day: 'Sunday', info: 'Sunday is 7th day.\nSunday is 7th day.\nSunday is 7th day.\nSunday is 7th day.\nSunday is 7th day.\nSunday is 7th day.\nSunday is 7th day.\n' }
];

const ContentShowcase = () => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const contentRef = useRef(null);
  const [springProps, api] = useSpring(() => ({ height: 'auto', config: { duration: 300 } }));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (contentRef.current) {
      api.start({ height: contentRef.current.scrollHeight });
    }
  }, [activeIndex, api]);

  return (
    <Box p={4} w={{ base: '99%', md: '90%', lg: '80%' }} maxWidth="100%">
      <Flex justify="center" mb={4}>
        {daysContent.map((content, index) => (
          <Box
            key={content.day}
            p={2}
            m={1}
            border="1px solid"
            borderColor={index === activeIndex ? 'blue.500' : 'gray.300'}
            borderRadius="md"
            cursor="pointer"
            onClick={() => setActiveIndex(index)}
          >
            {content.day}
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Flex>
      <animated.div style={{ ...springProps, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
        <Box
          ref={contentRef}
          p={4}
          borderRadius="md"
          boxShadow="lg"
          border="1px solid gray"
        >
          <Text fontSize="xl" fontWeight="bold" mb={2}>
            {daysContent[activeIndex].day}
          </Text>
          <Text whiteSpace="pre-wrap">{daysContent[activeIndex].info}</Text>
        </Box>
      </animated.div>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default ContentShowcase;```

